# How to find the power series solution of this ordinary differential equation using MMA

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

I already know that the solution of this differential equation $y''(x) - x*y(x) = 0$ can be expressed by the following power series:

$$y(x)=c0(1+\frac{x^{3}}{2\times3}+\frac{x^{6}}{2\times3\times5\times6}+\cdots\dfrac{x^{3n}}{2\times3\times5\times6\times\cdots\times(3n-1)3n}+\cdots)+c1(x+\frac{x^{4}}{3\times4}+\frac{x^{7}}{3\times4\times6\times7}+\cdots\dfrac{x^{3n+1}}{3\times4\times6\times7\times\cdots\times(3n)(3n+1)}+\cdots)=c0(1+\sum _{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{3 i}}{\prod _{j=1}^i (3 j-1) (3 j)})+c1(x+\sum _{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{3 i+1}}{\prod _{j=1}^i (3 j) (3
    j+1)})$$

In the above formula, `c0` and `c1` are arbitrary constants.

I want to know how to use MMA to find the power series solution of the above ordinary differential equation **and** the power series solution of the following differential equation:
$$y'(x)^2=\frac{9}{y(x)}-1$$

**Other examples for testing:**

```
DSolve[{y[x]*y''[x] == 1 + y'[x]^2, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

I also want to get the infinite power series solution of this above differential equation, but I haven't solved this problem yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, expansion around zero

```
ode = y''[x] - x y[x] == 0
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For second one

```
ode = (y'[x])^2 == 9/y[x] - 1
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with warning:

> ```
> AsymptoticDSolveValue::asdb There are multiple solution 
>   branches for the equations, but AsymptoticDSolveValue will return only
> ```

one

See help on `symptoticDSolveValue` for more info. This is new function added in 11.3

Comment: Thank you very much. But strictly speaking, your solution is only approximate, not infinite series, which is slightly unsatisfactory.

Comment: For first ODE, `DSolve` gives exact solution `AiryAi[x] C[1] + AiryBi[x] C[2]`. If we then expand the two Airy functions around 0, we get series involving exact values of Γ'. Thus `Series[AiryAi[x] ,{x, 0, 10{] begins `1/(3^(2/3) Gamma[2/3]) - x/(3^(1/3) Gamma[1/3]) + x^3/(
 6 3^(2/3) Gamma[2/3])`. How does one reconcile that with the asymptotic series above?